# Disable Bluetooth discoverable mode on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I found in the Android documentation how to turn Bluetooth discoverability mode on:

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

This will make the device discoverable for 300 seconds ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#EnablingDiscoverability)).

My question is: how to turn discoverability OFF before this timeout occurs? I'd like to replicate the corresponding setting in Settings|Wireless and networks|Bluetooth settings applet, that allows discoverability to be turned on and off with a click.

Any help?

Comment: Solved with reflection in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47452626/5239473

Answer (score 13):

Just send a new discoverable request with duration 1 (or 0 might even work):

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new
Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 1);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

Comment: Agreed, but it's the best/only solution I could find. So what does your app do?

Comment: It's just a simple widget to enable/disable discoverability, nothing fancy :)

Comment: Yeah 1 works. But, the user will be asked again to confirm :( Any other way?

Comment: According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) using 0 will put it in discoverable mode indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

`cancelDiscovery()` is not for this. This method can be used to stop the scanning of your device for other bluetooth devices. It is different from this to make device not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Care when using this method, it might be easily changed as it is hidden.

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();  
try {
    Method method = BluetoothAdapter.class.getMethod("setScanMode", int.class);
    method.invoke(bluetoothAdapter, BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to turn off bluetooth device discoverability.", e);
}
```

Also usable with `SCAN_MODE_NONE` and `SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE` (uses default duration)

[Source](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/2cd635)