# bluetoothAdapter.setName() is making device undiscoverable in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to change the bluetooth device name using `BluetoothAdapter#setName(String)` method, the method returns true which means the bluetooth adapter name is changed, but after that, the device is no longer discoverable from other devices. Any idea?

```
    BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    BluetoothAdapter lAdapter = manager.getAdapter();
    if (lAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        boolean isChanged = lAdapter.setName("TestName");
        if (isChanged) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bluetooth device name has been changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

This code is working fine on Android 8, Xiaomi MI MAX, the problem is on android 10, Xiaomi Redmi 9A

Comment: you can programatically set the scan mode in your application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723790/how-to-change-the-scan-mode-of-bluetooth-adapter-in-android